# How do I override a User Provider for testing with Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following security.yml:

```
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        bd_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Usuario
                property: email

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login

            provider: bd_provider

            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
```

And I'm authenticating for testing porpuses by this way:

```
protected function createClientWithAuthentication()
{
    /* @var $client Client */
    $client = static::createClient();

    /* @var $user UserInterface */
    $user = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('AppBundle:Usuario')->find(5);

    $firewallName = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), $firewallName, $user->getRoles());
    $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');
    $session->set('_security_' . $firewallName, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

    return $client;
}
```

But I would like to use a diferent provider for testing, like in_memory. So I added the following in my config_test.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        em_memoria:
            memory:
                users:
                    email@example.com:
                        password: senha
                        roles: 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'

    encoders:
            AppBundle\Entity\Usuario: plaintext

    firewalls:
        main:
            provider: em_memoria
```

But when I change my code that assemble the user to this:

```
$user = new Usuario();
$user
    ->setUsername('email@example.com')
    ->setPassword('admin')
    ->setRole('ROLE_USER_ADMIN');
```

The tests send me to the login page, as if I was using an incorrect user. What am I missing here? Is there anything else I should do?

If any other information is necesssary just tell me and I'll provide here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make it work, so I configured my database on the test environment to be a SQLite db. I also created some DataFixtures to load initial data, and called theese fixtures on my bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias as user provider and refer to different services in different environments.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        provider: app.user_provider
```

conf.yml:

```
services:
    app.user_provider:
       alias: bd_provider
```

conf_test.yml:

```
services:
    app.user_provider:
       alias: em_memoria
```

Comment: The definition of the provider must be in the same file that the definition of the service, or else I receive the following error:


[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]         
  Unable to replace alias "app.user_provider" with actual definition "bd_provider".  
                                                                                     

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]  
  You have requested a non-existent service "bd_provider".

Comment: I edited some code here and I did the following: I created a class TestUserProvider and implemented the custom provider that returns a user. Whe my test provider is specified as the first on the `providers` list, it is executed with success in my tests, but I'm not able to use the bd_provider anymore, even if I specify the `provider` key under my main firewall.